# Finite field extension implies algebraic closures isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I‘m wondering if the following statement is true for any field $F$:

> $F/\mathbb Q$ finite $\implies \overline F \cong \overline {\mathbb Q}$

I guess it‘s false but cannot disprove it. Can somebody give me a hint?

Comment: You can't disprove it because it's true. $F$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$. Any algebraic closure of $F$ is an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$. Any algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ contains a copy of $F$.